# При повторном открытие modal-окна ничего не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, modal

Есть кнопка, которая запускает модальное окно. При ее закрытие повторно вызвать не получается. Как решить?

```js
var createModal = (params) => {
  let html_modal = `
  <div class="modal-bg style="display: block">
   <div class="modal-wrap">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h1> ${params.head} </h1>
     <div class="modal-close">&times</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
     ${params.content}
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 `;
  document.body.innerHTML += html_modal; //Загружаем верстку

  document.querySelector('.modal-close').addEventListener('click', () => {
    closeModal(); //Если нажать на крестик - вызывется closeModal();
  });
  window.document.querySelector('.modal-bg').onclick = () => {
    closeModal(); //Если клацнуть на фон - вызывается closeModal();
  }
}

var closeModal = () => {
  document.querySelector('.modal-bg').style.display = 'none'; //Модалке отключаем дисплей
}

// Вызываем функцию
document.querySelector('.btn-modal').addEventListener('click', () => { //btn-modal - класс с кнопкой
  createModal({
    head: 'Testing',
    content: 'Hello world, my friend'
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal-wrap {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
}

.modal-header {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  background: blue;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.modal-header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modal.css">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .btn-modal {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 4px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      border-radius: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="btn-modal">
    Click me!
  </div>

  <script src="modal.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы перезаписываете `innerHTML` всего `body`, теряя обработчики.

В `body` добавьте элемент, который будете перезаписывать:

```
<body>

  <div class="btn-modal">
    Click me!
  </div>
  <div id="my_window_block">

  </div>
  <script src="modal.js"></script>
</body>
```

А в `createModal` пишите в блок `my_window_block`:

```
var createModal = (params) => {
    let html_modal = `
    <div class="modal-bg style="display: block">
        <div class="modal-wrap">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1> ${params.head} </h1>
                <div class="modal-close">&times</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                ${params.content}
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
`;

  document.getElementById("my_window_block").innerHTML = html_modal; //Загружаем верстку

  document.querySelector('.modal-close').addEventListener('click', () => {
    closeModal(); //Если нажать на крестик - вызывется closeModal();
  });
  window.document.querySelector('.modal-bg').onclick = () => {
    closeModal(); //Если клацнуть на фон - вызывается closeModal();
  }
}

var closeModal = () => {
  document.querySelector('.modal-bg').style.display = 'none'; //Модалке отключаем дисплей
}

// Вызываем функцию
document.querySelector('.btn-modal').addEventListener('click', () => { //btn-modal - класс с кнопкой
  createModal({
    head: 'Testing',
    content: 'Hello world, my friend'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в

```
document.body.innerHTML += html_modal
```

Вы пересоздаете все DOM-элементы, и у них после этого нет обработчиков событий.